# Generate script sql from "Entities" of spring-data-jdbc

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, database-schema, spring-data-jdbc

I need to create sql script using spring-data-jdbc.
Using spring-data-jpa I have no problems, but I want to know if there is the possibility of performing the scripts automatically using spring-data-jdbc

I achived it using spring-data-jpa, but I can not find information for spring-data-jdbc.

Can you help me ?, please.

```
#spring-data-jpa
spring:
 jpa:
    properties:
      javax:
        persistence:
          schema-generation:
            create-source: metadata
            scripts:
              action: drop-and-create
              drop-target : .\src\main\resources\drop.sql
              create-target: .\src\main\resources\create-script.sql
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet supported by Spring Data JDBC.

There is an issue for it you may want to watch: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-338